# $.ajax complete not doing anything with response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I can't seem to get this data to populate my select menus. I'm getting a response back from the ajax call, but the `.html` call seems to ignore it. It's interesting to note, I tried `success:` and `.done`, but those were actually blocking, and weren't firing at all.

```
$ ->
  $('#vehicle-query #make').on 'change', ->
    $.ajax
      type: 'get'
      dataType: 'script'
      url: '/vehicles/model_query'
      data:
        make: $(this).val()
    .complete (opt) ->
      $('#vehicle-query #model').html opt
      $('#vehicle-query #model').prop 'disabled', false
      $('#vehicle-query #year').val ''
      $('#vehicle-query #year').prop 'disabled', true
      $('#vehicle-query #style').val ''
      $('#vehicle-query #style').prop 'disabled', true
```

Another note, I'm making this request in Rails, and responding from the controller with:

```
render partial: 'vehicles/query_menu',
       object: @models,
       as: :options,
       locals: {select: 'Model'},
       layout: false
```

and building the response from a haml file.

Proof that I'm getting a response with what I want:

[image]

Comment: from image it looks like you are using some sort of plugin to modify `<select>`, if so you need to use plugin api methods to update

Comment: correct. `$('#vehicle-query #model')` is a `<select>` element. No plugin, here... you're looking at all of it. If I write raw html into the `.html` method, it does update the way it should. I can only think, maybe it's the way the haml file is rendering it? Are the line breaks botching it?

Comment: line breaks are perfectly valid in html

Comment: Why are you using `dataType: 'script'` when you expect `HTML`? This may be the issue as a `script` type will be executed before being returned so something may be happening there. It is best to use `html` or for > jQuery 1.5 you could do "script html" if your content-type returned by the server is set to `script`

Comment: i wanted you to be right, @MattGreen, but that gets me the same results.

Comment: Try using [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) instead as it is specialized for use with loading `HTML` from sources. It may be a parsing issue with the `HTML` that is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery ajax `complete` according to the documentation:

> The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x,
>   XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the
>   request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or
>   "parsererror").

So you're not getting the html response directly. The first argument `opt` in your case would be the jqXHR object. Call `opt.responseText` to get the html.

Comment: I suspect the reason that `success` isn't working is because of a badly formatted response. But anyway my solution above should work although it doesn't handle the "sad path" (when an error occurs).

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax**

The main issue you've got is that your `success` function of `ajax` doesn't work

I only learnt recently that the difference between `success` and `error` has nothing to do with the response type; it's all to do with whether the `ajax`request hit its target

It's interesting that `.complete` works for you, as in accordance with the reference provided by `Ahmed`, it will capture the `success` and `error` callbacks - suggesting to me that you've got a problem with either the response, or request of your ajax

--

Firstly, I would change your JS (to ensure it will work with Turbolinks):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on 'change', '#vehicle-query #make' ->
    $.ajax
      type: 'get'
      dataType: 'script'
      url: '/vehicles/model_query'
      data:
        make: $(this).val()
      success: (data) ->
        alert data
        $('#vehicle-query #model').html data
        $('#vehicle-query #model').prop 'disabled', false

        $('#vehicle-query #year').val ''
        $('#vehicle-query #year').prop 'disabled', true
        $('#vehicle-query #style').val ''
        $('#vehicle-query #style').prop 'disabled', true
```

Secondly, just because your `.html` method doesn't work, doesn't mean the thing is broken beyond repair. It simply means you're likely not calling the correct functionality.

Since you're trying to populate your `<select>` input, I was initially sceptical about the `.html` function. However, as I tested it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39ob1mth/), I found it was a valid use case.

So I'd actually look at what `Ahmed` was saying - it's likely the case that you're not calling the correct `data` callback. Try using the `success` function as above, or you may want to look at referencing the different data objects sent by the [`complete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) method:

```
Function( Event event, jqXHR jqXHR, PlainObject ajaxOptions )
```

This means you'll benefit from doing this:

```
.complete: (opt, data, x) ->
  //use data
```